# Php like counter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create 'like' counter.

Currently I use ajax with php and on button click in like.php I update count in database and echo back count number to jquery.

```
$('btn').on('click',function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'like.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: someData,
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response){

        //increase like shown on response

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }); 

 });
```

This would be triggering likes from client side.

---

I would like to do this on server side instead, so on button click to call php file:

Example (I put this in my page):

```
<a href="like.php?id=45">like</a>
```

And then in like.php update count in database as above.

2 questions:

1. is it possible for url not to change when I click this?
2. how would I echo back like count from like.php this way?  (because I dont use ajax to call like.php like in first example)

Comment: The answers to your questions would be to use AJAX, like you already do.  Why are you trying not to use AJAX?  What's the actual problem being addressed here?

Comment: 1. No, url will be changed anyway. 2. You can redirect back to the current page with the value query string (not suggested) / or set the value in session (not suggested). By the way if you redirect back to current page, by default, you could have taken the count from db and displayed it in the current page. So session or query string is not needed. Instead of doing all these, just use ajax. that would be best solution.

Comment: Question: What can you do to prevent me from calling this link via a job that i have written in php or whatever and is runnnig 1000 times per second?? How do you get valid data (means let one user only vote once)? Your approach does not have logic for that.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: That same problem exists in the AJAX version too.  While potentially a valid concern, that seems very much outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @David But it is an issue/problem that should before this question made right, or? So i gave a note on this :-) And hopefully the OP sees that an plain link in a href wont really work ;-) He has to use VOTE TOKENS or else.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: We don't know that it's a problem or that it hasn't been solved for this application already.  We could just as easily suggest that the OP doesn't use plain-text passwords when authenticating users.  It's a potential problem that should be solved if it hasn't already, but has nothing to do with the question being asked.  There are lots of things the OP *should* do in the scope of building their application.  Most of which are unrelated to the question.

Comment: @David Thats why i doing just comments at this question. And there is always a talk about sql injections when used plain sqls.... :-) As long a have not sayed something wrong, its ok for me, to drop a comment like this. But, bye i try to avoid cha...

Comment: Why down vote? 2. I dont reload the page obviously, my page is not just counter.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - i save user ip in db. I know its not much but its a start.

Answer (score 0):

to your first question: simply no!
But you could make it a submit button and do post to the same url wich wouldn't change the url and you can push data through submit...

to your second question -> your like.php has to return the whole html with your counter-value ;)

cheerio :)